# Проверка существования файла в случае если он находиться в сети

Tags: c#

Суть в том что программа подключается читает из xls файла данные, но этот файл может находиться как и на рабочей машине пользователя, так и на сервере в локальной сети. Всё работает отлично до того момента, как сеть отключается. И в случае если  файл был на сервере, то приложение подвисает в попытках найти файл в сети (здесь речь идёт именно при попытке проверить существование файла каждый раз при открытии контекстного меню). После этого приложение перестает видеть файл, даже если сеть появиться (перезапуск приложения не поможет), до того момента как файл заново прописать в параметрах приложения. Версия .NET 4.0.

```
if (!File.Exists(excel.bank)||mass==null)
                c_menu.Items[2].Enabled = false;
if(File.Exists(excel.bank)&&mass!=null)
                c_menu.Items[2].Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Что мешает кэшировать файл на устройстве, а ещё лучше - заменить Excel файл на СУБД?

Comment: Содержимое файла меняется несколько раз в день

Comment: Тогда всего лишь надо перед проверкой существования файла на сервере прежде проверять если доступ к серверу, например пинговать его.

Comment: Я описывал выше ситуацию. Файл может быть как и на сервере, так и на рабочей машине. Всё таки хотелось бы сделать более унифицировано. Как вариант, можно проверять путь. И если он на сервере, то проверять доступность сервера, но это выглядит как нагромождение костылей. В идеале приложение должно попытаться найти файл, если в течении 1 секунды его не нашло, то считать что его нет.

Comment: Если данные часто меняются и нужен универсальный вариант, то почему не использовать СУБД вместо того, чтобы городить велосипед из костылей?